# Does an AddHandler require parameters?

Tags: vb.net, addhandler

I'm trying to add a handler, but as soon as I'm targetting a method that has parameters, the handler fails. This is the simple code:

```
AddHandler App.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonUp, RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonUp

Private Sub RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseButtonEventArgs)

End Sub
```

This error won't let me build. When looking at the examples, I'm doing it right. This is the error I get:

> Error 3   Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Private Sub
>   RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonUp(sender As Object, e As
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)'.  C:\TFS\ProjectCollection\ItemManagementTool\ItemManagementTool.ClientApplication\Views\MainMenu.xaml.vb 82  70  ItemManagementTool.ClientApplication

I get a similar error for the "sender" parameter.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `AddressOf` keyword

```
AddHandler App.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonUp, AddressOf RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonUp
```

Comment: Appreciated this question and answer.  Thought I would add that I was making the mistake of having parenthesis at the end, i.e. RootVisual_MouseLeftButtonUp().  It doesn't like that, of course, but you don't know until you see it, as posted here.  Thanks!